# i have a simple code. how can i write tests for it?

Tags: php, automated-tests, phpunit, functional-programming

when im wrote this code, i didn't use phpunit and functional tests, because i don't know how to write tests for this code. I know how to write tests for other functions and code, but i don't know which test's required for this code. Can anybody explain ?
All functions is google adwords API. Not my own. I don't need to test them also.

```
    $adStatsSelector = new AdStatsSelector();
$adStatsSelector->dateRange = new
      DateRange('20100901','20101001');
$user = new AdWordsUser();
$user->LogDefaults();
$servicedAccountService = $user->GetServicedAccountService('v201008');
$selector = new ServicedAccountSelector(); 
$graph = $servicedAccountService->get($selector); 
foreach($graph->accounts as &$account) {
    $user->SetClientId($account->login);
    $campaignService = $user->GetCampaignService('v201008');
    $selector = new CampaignSelector(null,null,$adStatsSelector);
    $page = $campaignService->get($selector);
    $account->campaigns = $page->entries;
}
```

Comment: You test that for a given input, you receive a certain expected output. Neither your question, nor the contained code shows what in- and output are. Clarify please and we might be able to help you write a test for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the code stands it's hard to define tests because it's not in the form of something we can call; we can't vary inputs and make sure we get certain outputs.

So as best I can see the thing you can test is whether **graph** ends up populated with the expected data. Somehow you invoke this code and have a look at what's in graph.

Now looking at the code several questions come to mind:

1. Why is the date range hard coded?
2. What's that v201008, why is that hard coded?
3. Where's the error handling? Can those $user->??? methods fail?

So I would modify this code to generalise it, and put it in a function. We can then test the function. Imagine a function( in pseudo code)

```
 graph = getGraph(start, end, version)
```

now you can vary the inputs and check the response, but ... how do you know what the response should be? You may do best to mock the services you use. You can then also assert that you are calling services with the correct parameters, and for some tests force the services to raise error conditions.

Summary: Writing code to be testable really helps when you want to test things, in doing so you tend to focus on the dull but inportant stuff such as error handling.

Comment: +1 well written. You might want to include some links to a mocking library for php and maybe mention IoC/DI.

Comment: @Klaus thanks. One thing that puzzles me on SO, folks have lots of good ideas and are permitted to edit answers and improve them. It very rarely happens. If you've got a favourite mocking library why not edit the answer and mention it?

Comment: you are right. The thing is that I don't work with php and I don't want to recommend the first library I find by googling without having used it. Also I'm not *that* committed to improving your answer and (potentially) earning you extra reputation ;-) But you are right though. Very few people actually edit answers. It's much more common to edit questions. I guess it has to do with respect for the answerer really (*and* the rep thing probably).

Comment: @Klaus, I don't actually do any serious PHP myself, which is why I don't know of a mock lib to recommend. The reputation thing is certainly a factor for me too, humans work for rewards. It's a pity SO doesn't provide tangible reward for collaborative working.

Comment: thanks, your answer help me. i need write a testable code. And i need to use Mocks for 3d party classes.